# Replace default Wordpress search behavior with Sphinx

Tags: search, loop

I want to implement [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) in my Wordpress site but I'm not exactly sure how to change Wordpress search behavior to use Sphinx.

How do I get Sphinx Search engine to replace whatever Wordpress uses as default? I also want to display search results in a div with animations and search options on a static front page with only the site logo above it. If I use Sphinx, is there a way to use a Wordpress loop to return the search results with query_posts function?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Sphinx Search website lists three wordpress plugins on its [Plugin Page](http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=third_party). Maybe one (or more) of them does what you want?

- [Voce Connect](https://github.com/voceconnect/wp-sphinx-search). Wordpress Plugin.
- [Ivinco](http://www.ivinco.com/software/wordpress-sphinx-search/). Wordpress Plugin.
- [Gigaom](https://github.com/gigaOM/go-sphinx). Wordpress Plugin.  Filters WordPress' core WP Query to allow interoperability with and improve performance of other plugins and existing queries, including core taxonomy queries.